# \begin {eqnarray} does not work properly, in the latest version of (La)Tex?

Tags: miktex, eqnarray

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} \textwidth 160mm\textheight 235mm
\oddsidemargin-2mm \evensidemargin-2mm\topmargin-10mm
\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}
\expandafter\let\expandafter\oldproof\csname\string\proof\endcsname
\let\oldendproof\endproof
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{%
  \oldproof[\ttfamily \scshape \bf #1. ]%
}{\oldendproof}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\vs{\vspace*{-2mm}}
\def\ve{\varepsilon}
\def\T{{\rm T}}
\def\hat{\widehat}
\def\tilde{\widetilde}
\def\emp{\emptyset}
\def\conv{{\rm conv}\,}
\def \dist {{\rm dist}}
\def\dom{{\rm dom}\,}
\def\span{{\rm span}\,}
\def\epi{{\rm epi\,}}
\def\rge{{\rm rge\,}}
\def\mepi{{\rm\footnotesize epi\,}}
\def\Gph{{\rm gph}\,}
\def\mGph{{\rm\footnotesize gph}\,}
\def\Ker{{\sl Ker}\,}
\def\a{^{\ast}}
\def\p{^{\prime}}
\def\pp{^{\prime\prime}}
\def\om{\ominus}
\def\lra{\longrightarrow}
\def\Lra{\Longrightarrow}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\K{{\cal K}}
\def\N{{\cal N}}
\def\Lm{{\Lambda}}
\def\O{{\cal O}}
\def\S{{\cal S}}
\def\U{{\cal U}}
\def\V{{\cal V}}
\def\d{{\rm d}}
\def\sub{\partial}
\def\B{\mathbb B}
\def\EE{I\!\!E}
\def\RR{I\!\!R}
\def\BB{I\!\!B}
\def\o{\overline}
\def\oRR{\overline{\RR}}
\def\ox{\overline{x}}
\def\oy{\overline{y}}
\def\or{\overline{r}}
\def\oz{\overline{z}}
\def\ov{\overline{v}}
\def\og{\overline{g}}
\def\oF{\overline{F}}
\def\olm{\overline{\lambda}}
\def\olambda{\overline{\lambda}}
\def\S{{\cal S}}
\def\cl{{\rm cl}\,}
\def\mcl{{\rm\footnotesize Cl}\,}
\def\mCl{{\rm\footnotesize cl}\,}
\def\Ra{\Rightarrow}
\def\disp{\displaystyle}
\def\Lim{\mathop{{\rm Lim}}}
\def\F{Fr\'{e}chet}
\def\G{G\^{a}teaux}
\def\P{Painlev\'{e}}
\def\H{Hadamard}
\def\Limsup{\mathop{{\rm Lim}\,{\rm sup}}}
\def\Liminf{\mathop{{\rm Lim}\,{\rm inf}}}
\def\hhat#1{\hat{\vbox{\baselineskip=0pt\vskip-1.8pt
\hbox{$\hat{\vbox{\baselineskip=0pt\vskip-
0.8pt\hbox{$\!#1$}}}$}}}}
\def\HHat#1{\widehat{\vbox{\baselineskip=0pt\vskip-1.5pt
\hbox{$\widehat{\vbox{\baselineskip=0pt\vskip-
0.5pt\hbox{$#1$}}}$}}}}
\def\tto{\;{\lower 1pt \hbox{$\rightarrow$}}\kern -10pt
\hbox{\raise 2pt \hbox{$\rightarrow$}}\;}
\def\Hat{\widehat}
\def\Tilde{\widetilde}
\def\Bar{\overline}
\def\ra{\rangle}
\def\la{\langle}
\def\ve{\varepsilon}
\def\B{I\!\!B}
\def\h{\hfill\Box}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\def\ox{\bar{x}}
\def\oy{\bar{y}}
\def\oz{\bar{z}}
\def\col{\colon\!\!\!}
\def\ov{\bar{v}}
\def\ow{\bar{w}}
\def\ou{\bar{u}}
\def\ot{\bar{t}}
\def\op{\bar{p}}
\def\oq{\bar{q}}
\def\co{\mbox{\rm co}\,}
\def\cone{\mbox{\rm cone}\,}
\def\ri{\mbox{\rm ri}\,}
\def\inte{\mbox{\rm int}\,}
\def\gph{\mbox{\rm gph}\,}
\def\epi{\mbox{\rm epi}\,}
\def\dim{\mbox{\rm dim}\,}
\def\dom{\mbox{\rm dom}\,}
\def\mon{\mbox{\rm mon}\,}
\def\ker{\mbox{\rm ker}\,}
\def\proj{\mbox{\rm proj}\,}
\def\lip{\mbox{\rm lip}\,}
\def\reg{\mbox{\rm reg}\,}
\def\cov{\mbox{\rm cov}\,}
\def\aff{\mbox{\rm aff}\,}
\def\clco{\mbox{\rm clco}\,}
\def\cl{\mbox{\rm cl}\,}
\def\rank{\mbox{\rm rank}\,}
\def\d{{\mathrm d}}
%\def\substack#1#2{{\scriptstyle{#1}\atop\scriptstyle{#2}}}
\def\subsubstack#1#2#3{{{{\scriptstyle{#1}}\atop{\scriptstyle{#2}}}
\atop{\scriptstyle{#3}}}}
\def\h{\hfill\triangle}
\def\dn{\downarrow}
\def\O{\Omega}
\def\ph{\varphi}
\def\emp{\emptyset}
\def\st{\stackrel}
\def\oR{\Bar{\R}}
\def\lm{\lambda}
\def\gg{\gamma}
\def\dd{\delta}
\def\al{\alpha}
\def\Th{\Theta}
\def \N{I\!\!N}
\def\th{\theta}
\def\vt{\vartheta}
\def\vep{\varepsilon}
\def\ep{\epsilon}
\def\ss{\scriptsize }
\def\diag{\mbox{\rm diag}\,}
\def\bd{\mbox{\rm bd}\,}
\def\sce{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\def\verl{ \;\rule[-0.4mm]{0.2mm}{0.27cm}\;}
\def\verll{ \;\rule[-0.7mm]{0.2mm}{0.37cm}\;}
\def\verlm{ \;\rule[-0.5mm]{0.2mm}{0.33cm}\;}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Proposition}[Theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Remark}[Theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Corollary}[Theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Definition}[Theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Example}[Theorem]{Example}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{{\thesection}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}\sce
\begin{eqnarray}
ABCD
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

`

Above is my code , the below is my output !

[image]

There are two things which are different from my previous LaTex version.

1) what are those two rr ?

2) the output placed in the very right of line , not center?

Any help, would be extremely appreciated .

Comment: If you  do not align whatever, why don't you use `equation`?

Comment: Completing your code, I have no such problems. Anywat, eqnarray shouldn't be used: it produces bad spacing.

Comment: Thank You all for reply. Bernard,  I want use   " eqnarray "  in order can write in column way using &=& or &+&  @Bernard

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay thanks for advise next time I'll do that. But this time I need to fix eqnarray, Because I already wrote many pages using that, before installing new Miktex/Texmaker.  can you please let me how can I fix it? Do you need more part of my code?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did , please check it

Comment: It is very unusual to use a lot of `\def`'s and TeX assignments in a LaTeX document.

Comment: Note that despite the title this is not related to any changes in LaTeX, the definitions in this preamble would break any version of LaTeX (and many constructs other than eqnarray)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use `\def` in a LaTeX document, always use `\newcommand`, otherwise you do not get warned if you over-write important commands.

If you do

```
\def\span{{\rm span}\,}
```

then you will break every TeX alignment construct such as `eqnarray`, `tabular` etc.

Apart from avoiding the name `\span`  `\rm` shouldn't be used in latex (it is not defined by default) and to define an operator with the correct spacing you should use

```
\DeclareMathOperator\spn{span}
```

If you define

```
\def\or{\overline{r}}
```

then you break core boolean conditional tests. TeX syntax for a multi-way switch is `\ifcase .. a\or b \or c \else \fi` and if you redefine `\or` latex will not work at all.

Comment: Thanks   after deleting \or everting worked .

Comment: @Redshoes _please_ don't just delete `\or` !!! you need to delete all those `\def`

Comment: So you mean I go through my all commands an use "\newcommand" instead of \def ? and for defining operator I use  "\DeclareMathOperator" ?

Comment: There are many other problems but these are the start to fix, and absolutely necessary. Don't use TeX grammar in LaTeX document unless you absolutely know what you are doing.

Comment: @Redshoes most just need to be deleted, for example I haven't seen `\def\RR{I\!\!R}`  since the 1980s before fonts with ℝ became available, , `\a`, `\atop`, `\span`, `\h` , `\ss` (at least) are all core latex commands that should not be redefined